# Sum statement in PROC SQL on SAS

Tags: sql, sas, proc

When I am using a PROC SQL in SAS (SAS 9.3 via SAS EG on UNIX), I need to add up a few variables, but some of them are missing and it results into the overall number missing. For example:

```
PROC SQL; 
CREATE TABLE my_table AS 
SELECT 
A,
B,
C,
(A+B+C) as D
FROM source_table
```

In this example, if either A,B or C are missing, then D is missing too. I need something similar to a sum statement in data step, where any missing values are disregarded. For example, if C is missing then D should be equal to A and B.

Data step is not an option. I have to stay in PROC SQL.

Regards,
Vasilij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
PROC SQL; 
    CREATE TABLE my_table AS 
        SELECT A, B, C,
               coalesce(A, 0) + coalesce(B, 0) + coalesce(C, 0) as D
        FROM source_table ;
```

Comment: I like this answer over the SUM statement listed above for the reason of that SUM(A) and SUM(A,B,C) are in principle very different functions. First adding up the whole column A and second only the three values in the row. Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SUM` in PROC SQL as well

```
PROC SQL; 
CREATE TABLE my_table AS 
SELECT 
A,
B,
C,
sum(A,B,C) as D
FROM source_table
```

Comment: This works fine as long as sum has multiple arguments. Sum with a single argument sums the column value.

Comment: @Keith . . . I am not sure if this works, but even if it does, I would not recommend using it.  The behavior would be quite different from `select a, b, c, sum(a)`.

Comment: @Gordon It does work, with the caveat that you and Reese mention (i.e. it must have more than 1 argument).  I appreciate that SAS SQL is different to many other SQL applications in this instance, where the SUM function cannot be used in this way

Comment: @Reese Yes that's definitely worth mentioning in the answer for completeness. @GordonLinoff Specifying more than one argument is trivial, you can either use `sum(a,.)` or `sum(a,0)` depending on the outcome you are after.  If you then want to SQL aggregate `sum()` the result you can even use `sum(sum(a,0))`.

Comment: @RobertPenridge . . . I much prefer to use standard SQL functions for this, rather than relying on implementation-specific extensions -- particularly when the latter offer no benefit in performance and have the risk of a slight change (changing the number of arguments to one) utterly changing the meaning of the query.

Comment: @All, I support Gordon, the behavior between SUM(A) and SUM(A,B,C) is so different that for future support of the code, I would go with coalesce.

Comment: @GordonLinoff While I agree that `coalesce()` is more transferable to other DBs, I don't agree with the 'risk' comment.  I could make the reverse argument that `coalesce(A, 0) + ...` could easily break if you were to make a very slight modification to `coalesce(0, A) + ... `.  This could actually be a typo that would be hard to find if there were a lot of vars being `+`d. This would not be an issue with `sum()` as sum(0,A,B) is the same as `sum(A,0,B)` etc...  Personally I like to take advantage of the toolset available to me in the language I am working in so I can work smarter/faster.